# How can I check if the user input is a word and not a special character like (*!?)?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this code(Option1):

```
if(!firstName.getText().toString().matches("/w+/")){
            error = error + getString(R.string.error_first_name_incorrect_resgister_activity) +"\n";
```

And I have this code(Option2) that doesnt do what is expected(allow the user to only insert those characters)

```
if(!lastName.getText().toString().matches("/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.\'-]+$/u")){
            error = error + getString(R.string.error_last_name_incorrect_resgister_activity) +"\n";
```

Comment: if the input `length` is more than 1 obviously its not a single character.

Comment: Dude I want to check if the user inputs any *?!

Comment: @Null is absolutely right! Use String.length() method to check that.

Comment: If the `length` return +0 then the input is not empty

Comment: @Jose check out the answer man.

Comment: I explained badly. I dont want the length. By character i mean special characters like *?!,

Comment: Yep, my code does the same.

Comment: Check out @W4R10CK answer , and please edit your question

Comment: nd what goes wrong with option 2?

Comment: Yes but imagine youre a german and you want to write letter with special characters? I want an option for all of that :/

Comment: option 2 when i put a name like ("jose") it gives a popup error(that I have created)

Comment: @Jose German letters have the same Latin Alphabet?

Comment: "porządku" this word in Polish maybe dont pass your regex

Comment: Try this 
   `/^[a-zA-Z\-_ ’'‘ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ]$/`

Comment: see the updated code

Comment: AFAIK `matches` is a method of classes `Matcher`  and `Pattern`, not a method of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern `(?ui)\w+` to match with unicode symbols

[Java Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(your_text_string);
        boolean b = m.find();

        if (b) {
            // error occurred special chars
        }
```

Comment: This does't match letters like `çéèàù`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14841236)

Comment: @Joseph, the question is asked to find the special chars again it was corrected to German Language.

Comment: Can you make at least your answer more verbose? The code-only answer can solve the problem but some user need and desire an explanation.

Comment: I appreciate your Idea, will keep in mind. Thanks @Joseph

Answer (score 0):

First as [Null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834682/null) suggested you could just check the string length. Like this:

```
if(firstName.getText().toString().length < 5){
            error = error + getString(R.string.error_first_name_incorrect_resgister_activity)
```

or you could also modify your regex so the user has to give atleast 5 letters using a quantifier(`{5,}`). Then your code would look like this:

```
if(!lastName.getText().toString().matches(/\w{5,}/u)){
        error = error + getString(R.string.error_last_name_incorrect_resgister_activity) +"\n";
```

or

```
  if(!lastName.getText().toString().matches(/^[a-zA-Z\-_ ’'‘ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħ‌​įƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍ‌​ĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐ‌​ÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔá‌​àâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçď‌​ḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧ‌​ğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴ‌​ĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖ‌​ǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐ‌​ĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ň‌​ñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖ‌​ŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨ‌​ŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽ‌​Ẓŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùû‌​üǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳ‌​ỹƴźżžẓ]$/)){
            error = error + getString(R.string.error_last_name_incorrect_resgister_activity) +"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Character.isLetter(c)` as below:

```
    char[] charArray= lastName.getText().toCharArray();

    for(Character c :charArray ){
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)){
            error = error + getString(R.string.error_last_name_incorrect_resgister_activity) +"\n";
            break;
        }
    }
```

**Testing:**

```
char c1= '-';
char c2= 'A';
char c3= 'ę';
char c4= 'ð';
char c5= 'ã';
boolean flag1 =Character.isLetter(c1);
boolean flag2 =Character.isLetter(c2);
boolean flag3 =Character.isLetter(c3);
boolean flag4 =Character.isLetter(c4);
boolean flag5 =Character.isLetter(c5);
System.out.println(flag1);
System.out.println(flag2);
System.out.println(flag3);
System.out.println(flag4);
System.out.println(flag5);
```

Result:

```
false
true
true
true
true
```

**Edit:**

Also if you need to consider digits as a valid characters(Not a special characters) then you need to use `Character.isDigit(c)` :

```
if(!Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isDigit(c))
```

Comment: OP wants to allow some characters like: ` ,.\'-`

Comment: Does the OP mentioned that in the question ?

Comment: Sure, look at option 2.

Comment: well in that case he should check it manually like :
`if(c != ',') .... `